# Replacing specific part of a sting

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2000, string-formatting

I have a large table with IT products (nearly 3 million records) in there I could see rocords like..

```
1 Port Euro Wall Charger + Uk Adapter 5v 2.1a For IPod / iPhone / iPad - White - Ip-653
```

In here as you can see 'IPod' is not in standard format (iPod). So I came up with this SQL and implemented following.

```
update tablename
set dsc = replace(dsc, 'iPod', 'iPod')
where dsc not like'%iPod%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
and dsc like '%iPod%'
```

After applying this to all records, it has done the formatting which I want but it has done some unwanted changes too, like...

```
100in **TriPod** Canvas CarryinGBag For T100uwv1 Screen
```

is there a way to overcome this kind of changes, can I use RegEx. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding space before and after ipod in like clause will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Unless ipod appears at the start or end of the data, that is.

Comment: or clause can be added with a a space before and a space after that.This even can be solved with the help of regular expressions

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
where dsc like 'iPod %' 
or dsc like '% iPod %'
or dsc like '% iPod'
```

to match where ipod is used as a word, rather than within a word.

Comment: As I said there are about 3 million+ records in table, this will slowdown whole process.

Comment: It's presumably a one off task.

Comment: No this is a job runs daily